# Scala futures using Future.sequence but having issues with returning a tuple

Tags: scala, future

I am having some trouble trying to return a tuple when I am using `Future.sequence` below:

```
type UserId = Int
  type GameId = Int
  type Score = Double

  case class Game(id: GameId)

  def findGame(id: GameId): Future[Game] = ???
  def findUserGames(id: UserId): Future[Seq[(GameId, Score)]] = ???

  def findGames(id: UserId): Future[Seq[(Game, Score)]] = {
    val userGames = findUserGames(id)

    // ******* I am stuck here
    val games: Future[Seq[Game]] = userGames.flatMap(x => Future.sequence(x.map(y => findGame(y._1))))    
  }
```

How can I return a tuple of `(Game, Score)` when the Future.sequence call is just returning me a `Seq[Game]`?

Also, if we didn't have `Future.sequence`, how would we be able to mimic what it does?
i.e. converting a `List[Future[Game]]` into a `Future[List[Game]]` ?

Comment: Try to use `Future.traverse` instead of `Future.sequence` as it is more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```scala
def findGames(id: UserId): Future[Seq[(Game, Score)]] = {
  findUserGames(id).flatMap(gameIdToScoreSeq =>
    Future.traverse(gameIdToScoreSeq)(gameIdToScore =>
      findGame(gameIdToScore._1).map((_, gameIdToScore._2))
    )
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

just by keeping track of what is what by name, as a oneliner, you can do

```
def findGames(id: UserId)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Seq[(Game, Score)]] =
  findUserGames(id).flatMap(games =>
    Future.sequence(games.map { case (gameid, score) =>
      findGame(gameid).map(game => game -> score)
    })
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need one more map:

```
val games: Future[Seq[(Game, Score)]] = userGames.flatMap(x => Future.sequence(x.map(y => findGame(y._1).map(z => (z, y._2)))))
```

As you can see it's getting a little bit convoluted. You could make your code more readable (arguably) by using for-comprehensions and pattern matching:

```
val games2: Future[Seq[(Game, Score)]] = for {
  games <- userGames
  result <- Future.sequence(games.map {
    case (gameId, score) => 
      for {
        game <- findGame(gameId)
      } yield (game, score)
  })
} yield result
```